# Can I get rid of � by installing unicode packages from project interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I have just imported a csv file with ’ as one of the content in the cells.

When parsing the contents using csv reader, the cell with ’ ended up with � and it is difficult to work with this as I received the following error message:

```
unsupported characters in input
```

I have attempted to replace the string using the following but it doesn't work:

```
col[2] = str(col[2]).replace("�", "'")
```

I have looked this up in the web and it seemed like there are missing characters and glyphs. I'd like to ask if this can be solved by installing unicode packages with the project interpreter? I am currently using pycharm.

Comment: Use the `unicodecsv` package or move to Python 3. The Python 2 `csv` module can't work with Unicode data.

Comment: Is that U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK or U+0092 from Micosoft's cp1252 encoding, being the close single smart quote?

Comment: @JGNI The `U+NNNN` notation refers to Unicode code points. Character `U+0092` is a control character with the description "Private Use 2". The "right single quotation mark", character `U+2019`, is encoded in CP-1252 with the byte value 92 (hexadecimal). It's the same character.

Comment: @lenz I was wondering what encoding his original text was as I've seen  `’` rendered as `�` even when the text is assumed to be cp1252